# Probability that a 1-D zero mean random walk remains at each step below a function of the number of steps

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

Let $W_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_i$ be a random walk on $\mathbb{R}$, where the $X_i$ are i.i.d., symmetric around the origin random variables ($X\sim -X$), such that $-1\leq |X(\omega)| \leq 1$ $\forall\omega\in\Omega$, $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ and $Var(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma^2$. I would like to bound from above the following probability as a function of $k$:
$$
P\Bigl(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{k}\Bigl\{W_n \leq\sqrt{n}\Bigr\}\Bigr)\leq h(k) \mbox{ ?}
$$
where $\lim_{k\to\infty} h(k) =0$, because I manage to prove it using zero-one Kolmogorov's law and the fact that $\frac{W_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to a normal random variable.

I know that it may be a really simple question, although I just can not find the right bound.. I have tried lots of different techniques but none of them seem to work properly. I think that a useful fact is the simmetry ( since $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},W_n\sim-W_n$ ) and the fact that $W_n$ has zero mean and (in general) bounded moments.

Comment: Can't you just note that $E[|X_i^3|]< 1$ and then apply Berry-Essen?          
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry\[Dash]Esseen_theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry-Esseen_theorem

Comment: Yeah, I've already thought about it, although it gives a bound on the CDF of $\frac{W_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ .. how to use this fact to bound the intersection of all of these events?

Comment: It's not a good bound, but obviously
$$P(\cap_{n=1}^k \{W_n\leq \sqrt{n}\})\leq \min_{n=1,2\ldots,k} P(W_n \leq \sqrt{n}).$$  If $\sigma<9/10$, $P(W_n \leq \sqrt{n})\approx 1$ for large $n$.  The case where $\sigma=1$ is interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! In my case I have that $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2}\implies\sigma = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} < 9/10$. In general $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(W_n\leq\sqrt{n}) = P(Z \leq \sqrt{2}) \approx 0.921026$ where $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.. how to use these informations to prove that the sequence of the probabilities of those intersections is bounded above by $h(k)$ which is a monotone decreasing function?

Comment: I guess $h(k)\rightarrow 0$ because the events $W_n\leq n$ and $W_{n^2} \leq n^2$ are almost independent for $n>10$.

Comment: Also, you are correct and I was wrong when I wrote $\sigma<9/10$ implies $P(W_n\leq \sqrt{n})\approx 1$.  LOL.

Comment: Yeah, $h(k)\to 0$.. although how we can "measure" the decreasing rate of $h(k)$? I would like to know the form of this function that bounds from above that probability